# android how to align buttons?

Tags: android-layout, android

i have three buttons so some size, now i need to put the 4th button below the 2nd button and aligned center of the 4th button with the center of the 2nd button.

i am having a little trouble doing that, any ideas?

```
 

!---!---!---!
!   !   !   !
!---!---!---!
  !-------!
  !       !
  !-------!
```

i have been playing around with gravity and align center and stuff but still could not find what i need.
This thing is not letting me post without a few more lines. I wonder if adding this line would make a difference?

Comment: can you post your layout code too?

Comment: the 1st three answers did not really solve my problem, my actual layout is complex enough with lots more components and relative layout. But thanks anyway everyone i am just changing my design rather than try to solve this UI problem. Dont have the time nor the patience anymore for UI designing.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the other solutions posted rely on simply centering the fourth button in the screen, but don't address how to achieve this if the *second button* **isn't** centered.

`ConstraintLayout` is the perfect layout to use as the parent to accomplish this. The most important thing that `ConstraintLayout` lets you do is center one view based on another, regardless of the position of the "anchor" view.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/two"
        android:text="ONE"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/one"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/three"
        android:text="TWO"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/two"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:text="THREE"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/two"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/two"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/two"
        android:text="FOUR"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_buttons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Second" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Third" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_buttons"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Forth" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this

```
<LinearLayout
 android:weightSum="3">
 <Button
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
 <Button
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
 <Button
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
 android:weightSum="3">
 <Button
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Obviously fill in the requisite tag requirements

Comment: can i do this with relative layout as well? or does it work with just linear layout?

Comment: The "layout_weight" is a property of children of a LinearLayout and the "weightSum" property is only available on a LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

Create two LinearLayouts with the same width. Put the first three buttons in the first LinearLayout and the 4th in the second one. Add `android:gravity="center"` to the second LinearLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B2" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@id/layout1"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, this will solve your problem. happy to help

```
 <LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```